Transferring to another phone, does it take up storage?
Soon, I will receive an iPhone 14 Pro Max (256GB). I want to transfer about 100GB worth of data from my iPhone 13 mini (128 GB). I want to ensure that I can use the full capacity without being limited by the 13 mini. After the transfer, will it use up the 13 mini's data?

"After the transfer, will it use up the 13 mini's data?" Uncertain what you mean about this question. Seeing that the 14 Pro Max has double the available storage, you'll be left with ~ 156GB storage on the Max.

Are you talking about data as in stored on device, data as used by your SIM, or something else?

"I want to ensure that I can use the full capacity without being limited by the 13 mini." I'm not sure what you mean by that, please clarify to avoid your question getting closed: Are you going to use the mini? If not, why do you care about the mini's storage left? If I'm getting this wrong, please clarify.

To copy data between devices, you need the following:

Adequate space on the device you are copying to (equal to or greater than what you are copying from).
Adequate 'working' space on the devices so that the files can be copied and the system can function (this is generally about 20%).


Will I be able to use the phone's full capacity?

Yes. Assuming your iPhone 14 Pro Max has enough free space, you can absolutely copy all of the data from your iPhone 13 mini. Afterwards, whatever space is left over (about 150 GB, based on your numbers), will remain free for your use.

After the transfer

After the data is copied, there will be two copies of it (one on the old phone, one on the new). The old phone will not automatically be cleared (you are copying the data, not moving it.) However, once the data is all on your new iPhone 14 Pro, you will free to reset/erase the old phone and use it for whatever other things you would like.

I would recommend doing a light clean on the iPhone 13.

Review the storage in the settings app
Make a backup to a computer
Make a backup to iCloud

The less you transfer, the less chance of a timeout or error causing you to erase the new phone and attempt a second transfer (not a huge risk, you just lose some time and the vast majority of transfers are uneventful and error-free).
The only wrinkle is if you have data stored in the cloud, optimize storage might use data on the new device, so I would connect to WiFi and disable cellular data if you’re worried about overage and want to download a copy of the data for the last backup before starting the transfer.
The new phone will be in no way limited due to apps, settings and files (a.k.a data) coming from a smaller device. It will take all the data it can fit and then mange that data as you configure the device.
